# How to stop function from appComponent into homeComponent. Angular2

Tags: angular

Need advice, cannot find a way.
I have appComponent with Logout
and function:

```
 logout () {
   "HOMECOMPONENT??".clearInterval(this.timer); //it should go to homeComponent and clearInterval
  this.authenticationService.logout((result) => this.isLogged());
}
```

When I press logout, first need to clear interval in other component called homeComponent.if'ts possible? how to do this?

Comment: Use a Shared Service

Comment: what do you mean? can you send a link with example?

Comment: Create a new service class, `SharedService.ts` and then add your `start()` and `clearInterval()` functions.

Comment: Take a look here how to create a `Service` in Angular 2 https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `HomeComponent` is a direct child of `AppComponent` then you can reference it with `ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild(HomeComponent)
homeComponent: HomeComponent

stopHomeTimer() {
    this.homeComponent.stopTimer();
}
```

http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/